# mpi4py - using a type for matrix column

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

Using mpi4py, I have created a code which defines a new datatype to hold a matrix's column and send it to other MPI process:

```
column = MPI.INT.Create_vector(4, 1, 4)
column.Commit()
if rank == 0:
        matrix = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
                           [5, 6, 7, 8],
                           [9, 10, 11, 12],
                           [13, 14, 15, 16]], dtype=np.intc)
        comm.Send([matrix, 1, column], 1)
else:
        matrix = np.array([[-1, -1, -1, -1],
                           [-2, -2, -2, -2],
                           [-3, -3, -3, -3],
                           [-4, -4, -4, -4]], dtype=np.intc)
        comm.Recv([matrix, 1, column], source=0)
        print(matrix)
```

This works, as long as only the first column of the matrix is concerned. The program prints:

```
[[ 1 -1 -1 -1]
 [ 5 -2 -2 -2]
 [ 9 -3 -3 -3]
 [13 -4 -4 -4]]
```

How do I go about sending a second column of matrix from process 0 to process 1? When I try to send it using `comm.Send([matrix[0,1], 1, column], 1)`, the receiving process inserts values `[2, -136678432, 0, 0]` into its matrix. Thus I believe that somehow I access ndarray's memory in a wrong manner.

If I translate this code to C and send using `MPI_Send (&matrix[0][1], 1, column, 1, 123, MPI_COMM_WORLD)` everything works and second column is transferred to process 1. How can I make the code work in Python/mpi4py? Please also note that I'd prefer the solution to still use the vector MPI type as declared in the first line (`column = MPI.INT.Create_vector(4, 1, 4)`).

Comment: @VictorEijkhout As for the first column, please see my edit. I also believe that numpy supports both C and Fortran order, at least that's how I see the documentation at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html (*Specify the memory layout of the array. If object is not an array, the newly created array will be in C order (row major) unless ‘F’ is specified, in which case it will be in Fortran order (column major)*)

Comment: My comment was completely wrong and now deleted. The problem is that derived types (with the exception of `subarray`, which will solve your problem) have to start at the beginning of the buffer. So you explicitly need to get hold of the address of the so-many-th element, which is what you did in your solution. Or use the `subarray` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to alter the `Send` part in my sample code as follows: `comm.Send([np.frombuffer(matrix.data, np.intc, offset=4), 1, column], 1)`

After experimenting, I have found that `Send` has problems reading from memory buffer when it's given as `matrix[0,1]`. We have to explicitly tell it to read from memory held by matrix (`matrix.data` part) and give an offset into that memory. As numpy by default stores the data in C order, we have to move 4 bytes ahead.